# Why is my Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function contactChange() {
        var contact = document.getElementbyId("contact");
        if (contact.style.display == "none") {          
            contact.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            contact.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is my site:

http://www.andrewjalexander.com/

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Error?  Code not being executed?  What calls the contactChange() method?.

Comment: Also, if you use jquery this whole thing would be `$('#contact').toggle()`

Comment: And if you do not use jQuery, this would be `var o = document.getElementById("contact"); o.style.display = (o.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none");` and would load and run magnitudes faster and require magnitudes less memory.

Comment: Magnitudes?  Really?  How much is a "magnitude" here?  I think the word your looking for is "negligible"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementbyId`. (In JS, name of variables and functions are case-sensitive)

Debugging tip : Look at the JS console (F12 in Google Chrome and IE9, Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox). In this case, following error can be seen:

[image: Debugging console in Google chrome]

It shows where the error happened (line 260 in your HTML/JS code) and what the error is(Object `#<HTMLDocument>` has no method `getElementbyId`).

Answer (score 4):

It's `getElementById`, not `getElementbyId`. Note the upper case "B".

Answer (score 4):

You're going to hate yourself for this, but you put `getElementbyId()` instead of `getElementById()`.  Note the capitalized "B" in the second version.

Answer (score 1):

Its `getElementById` in place of getElementbyId

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide then show a element on scroll I had to go this route. Basically i tried to use window so I used 'body'

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').scroll(function() {
 var scroll = $('body').scrollTop();
 if (scroll <= 50 ) {
     console.log(scroll);
   we
    } else {
    $("#label").css('fill', 'none');
    $(".label").addClass(".transition");
 }
 if (scroll <= 150) {
    $(".sizeLG").css('color', '#ffffff');
 } else {
    $(".sizeLG").css('color', '#00000000');
    $(".sizeLG").addClass(".transition");
 }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your id or class you used in html code will accordingly .(dot) Or #(hash) with their name.

Ex:

```
   For id:
   html:

  <div  id= idName>
          ****Some code****
   <\div>

  Javascript:
  var VariableName = document.querySelector( "#idName");
   Or
  var VariableName = document.getElementById( "#idName");

  For class:   
 html:
  <div  id= className>
          ****Some code****
   <\div>
  Javascript
  var VariableName = document.querySelector( ".className");
   Or
  var VariableName = document.getElementById( ".className");
```